# Select polygons by location of points using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join

I would like to select polygons that contain at least a point. I can use QGIS's tool called "Select by location: Select all buildings by location of point".

Is there a python alternative?

So far, I wrote a jupyter notebook and worked with GeoPandas.

I have tried

```
import pandas as pd

polygon_layer = gpd.read_file(r'file.shp') 
excel = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

points_layer = gpd.GeoDataFrame(excel, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(excel.X, excel.Y))

subset = gpd.sjoin(polygon_layer, points_layer, how='inner', predicate='within')
```

However, the spatial join does not work.

Comment: Do you get any error? You don't define a coordinate system for point layer.

Comment: yes sir I do `point.crs = {'init' : 'epsg:25832'}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of `predicate='within'`, it searches polygons within the points. This is not possible.

Change `predicate='within'` to `predicate='contains'`.

Comment: Thank you sir, you are right. The right code is:

`subset = gpd.sjoin(polygon, points, how='inner', predicate='contains')`